# Render dynamic form based on dropdown

Tags: html, angular, primeng, angular9

i am trying to create dynamic form based on dropdown but i get the following error when i try it:

```
field-builder.component.ts.FieldBuilderComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined
  at FieldBuilderComponent.get isValid [as isValid] (field-builder.component.ts:45)
  at Object.updateDirectives (field-builder.component.ts.FieldBuilderComponent.html:26)
  at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:45259)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44271)
  at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
  at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:44565)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44278)
  at callViewAction (core.js:44637)
  at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:44594)
  at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:44272)
```

My **FormComponent** file is as follows:

```
export class FormTemplateComponent implements OnInit {
  public form: FormGroup;
  unsubcribe: any;
  types: type[];
  selectedType: type;
  isValid: boolean = false;
  uploadedFiles: any[] = [];

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService , private templateService : TemplateService) {
    this.types = [{ obj_type: "BS" }, { obj_type: "MS" }];
  }

  public fields = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedType = this.types[1];
    this.getTemplates();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.isSelected();
  }


  onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
      this.messageService.add({
        severity: "info",
        summary: "File Uploaded",
        detail: file.name
      });
    }

    console.log("eee", event);
  }

  ChangingValue() {
    if (this.selectedType.obj_type == "MS") {
        this.isValid= true 
        this.getTemplates(); }
      if (this.selectedType.obj_type == "BS") {
        this.isValid= false ;   
        this.getTemplates();   }
    //this.resetChildForm();

  }

  getTemplates() {
    this.templateService.getTemplates(this.selectedType.obj_type).subscribe( res =>{
      // if (this.selectedType.obj_type == "MS") {
      //   this.fields = res[0] ;      }
      // if (this.selectedType.obj_type == "BS") {
      //   this.fields = res[1] ;      }

      console.log(  "Eae", res );
      this.fields = res;
      // console.log(this.fields);
      // console.log(this.fields1);
      this.isValid = true;
    })
  }

  getFields1() {
    return this.fields;
  }
}
```

**FormComponent.html** is as follows:

```
<p-toast [style]="{ marginTop: '80px' }"></p-toast>
<h1 class="text-center">Dynamic Form</h1><div class="ui-fluid ui-g" style="width: 80%; margin-left: 10%;">
<div class="form-group ui-g-12 ">
  <label for="sel1">Select Type:</label>
  <select
    class="form-control"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedType"
    (change)="ChangingValue()"
  >
    <option [ngValue]="type" *ngFor="let type of types">
      {{type.obj_type}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div> 
<div class="ui-g-12 ">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Dynamic Forms</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <!--
        <dynamic-form-builder
          *ngIf="!isValid"
          [fields]="getFields()"
        >
        </dynamic-form-builder>
      -->
      <dynamic-form-builder
        *ngIf="isValid"
        [fields]="getFields1()"
      ></dynamic-form-builder>
      <dynamic-form-builder
        *ngIf="!isValid"
        [fields]="getFields1()"
      ></dynamic-form-builder>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**DynamicForm.ts** is as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-form-builder',
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit.emit(this.form.value)" [formGroup]="form" class="form-horizontal">
      <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
          <field-builder [field]="field" [form]="form"></field-builder>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row"></div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})

export class DynamicFormBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSubmit = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() fields: any[] = [];

  form: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let fieldsCtrls = {};
    for (let f of this.fields) {
      if (f.type != 'checkbox') {
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(f.value || '', Validators.required)
      } else {
        let opts = {};
        for (let opt of f.options) {
          opts[opt.key] = new FormControl(opt.value);
        }
        fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormGroup(opts)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i am getting error in this file **fieldbuilder.ts**:

```
@Component({
  selector: "field-builder",
  template: `
    <div class="form-group row" [formGroup]="form">
      <label
        class="col-md-3 text-center form-control-label"
        [attr.for]="field.label"
      >
        {{ field.label }}
        <strong class="text-danger" *ngIf="field.required">*</strong>
      </label>
      <div class="col-md-9" [ngSwitch]="field.type">
        <textbox *ngSwitchCase="'text'"   [field]="field" [form]="form"></textbox>
        <dropdown
          *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'"
          [field]="field"
          [form]="form"
        ></dropdown>
        <checkbox
          *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"
          [field]="field"
          [form]="form"
        ></checkbox>
        <radio *ngSwitchCase="'radio'" [field]="field" [form]="form"></radio>
        <file *ngSwitchCase="'file'" [field]="field" [form]="form"></file>
        <div
          class="alert alert-danger my-1 p-2 fadeInDown animated"
          *ngIf="!isValid && isDirty"
        >
          {{ field.label }} is required
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class FieldBuilderComponent {
  @Input() field: any;
  @Input() form: any;

  get isValid() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].valid;
  }

  get isDirty() {
    return this.form.controls[this.field.name].dirty;
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

I get the error when I change the value in the dropdown to render a different template. If the name of the input is the same it renders normally but if the field input name changes from the original template name it gives me an error, specifically that it is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so guys! i resolved this problem just by rendering dynamic form on:

```
    ngOnChanges()
    {
     let fieldsCtrls = {};
        for (let f of this.fields) {
          if (f.type != 'checkbox') {
            fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormControl(f.value || '', Validators.required)
          } else {
            let opts = {};
            for (let opt of f.options) {
              opts[opt.key] = new FormControl(opt.value);
            }
            fieldsCtrls[f.name] = new FormGroup(opts)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

instead of

```
    ngOnInit(){
    }
```